# angular-compiler-cli not working?

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli

I'm trying to use the [Angular Template Compiler](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/@angular/compiler-cli) just to investigate it, I know it's in early stages but the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for RC5 is mentioning it already.  I created a small "hello, world" project and I can run `ngc`, but it never produces the `.ngFactory.ts` files, I only see a `.metadata.json` file.

You can see it by cloning the [angular 2 quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).  Running `$(npm bin)/tsc` works fine and compiles the typescript in the 'app' directory to javascript with map files.

Next I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/@angular/compiler-cli) and installed node modules (upgrading typescript):

```
npm install --save @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next 
@angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

Now running `$(npm bin)/tsc` still works and produces `.js` and `.js.map` files.  I delete those files and run `$(npm bin)/ngc` and it produces the `.js` and `.js.map` files, along with two new files:

```
 app.component.metadata.json
 app.module.metadata.jason
```

It looks like those files contain metadata from the decorators basically:

```
{"__symbolic":"module","version":1,"metadata":{"AppComponent":
{"__symbolic":"class","decorators":[{"__symbolic":"call","expression":
{"__symbolic":"reference","module":"@angular/core","name":"Component"},
"arguments":[{"selector":"my-app","template":
"<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>"}]}]}}}
```

But `ngc` produces no output to the console, and I don't see any `ngFactory` files that should be there.  Originally typescript@next gives me 2.1.0-dev.20160813, and packages say unmet peer dependency expecting 1.9.0 so I install 1.9.0-dev.20160627-1.0 but I get the same result.  I've also tried `$(npm bin)/ngc -p .` which does the same thing and `$(npm bin)/ngc -p app` which gives a bunch of errors because it can't find the core-js types (Promise, Set, Map, etc.).

Comment: Are you running "ngc –p /src"? It works for me on an existing project...

Comment: No, but because my tsconfig isn't in /src :)